# loadHTMLString baseURL:nil not working in iOS5

Tags: xcode, uiwebview, ios5

I got a problem with UIWebView. I want to render my own html code in UIWebView.

if I use the below code, it's working fine.

```
    NSBundle *thisBundle = [NSBundle mainBundle];
    NSString *path = [thisBundle pathForResource:@"foo" ofType:@"html"];
    NSURL *baseURL = [NSURL fileURLWithPath:path];
    [self.webView loadHTMLString:@"foo.html" baseURL:baseURL];
```

I want to render the html with below code. But it's not working. foo.html contains exactly the same content with the NSString* one. Any hints? Thanks in advance. =)

```
    NSString* one = @"<html><head><title></title></head><body><img src=\"image.jpg\"/></body></html>";
    [self.webView loadHTMLString:one baseURL:nil] ;
```

Answer (score 23, accepted):

I use this code that works perfectly :

```
NSString* htmlContent = @"<html><head><title></title></head><body><img src='image.jpg' /></body></html>";
[self.webView loadHTMLString:htmlContent baseURL:[NSURL fileURLWithPath:[[NSBundle mainBundle] bundlePath]]];
```

Bu sure that image.jpg is included into your project.

Comment: Hi, I don't want to read local html file. I want to use directly like this. NSString* one = @"<html><head><title></title></head><body><img src=\"image.jpg\"/></body></html>";

Comment: @moon : yes, sorry, just replace htmlContent with your HTML. That was was I did when writing this code. I edit my answer.

Answer (score 1):

create JS file **demo.js** and add code

`var hello = function(str){
       return str;
};`

add UIWebView => To embed JavaScript in a dummy html file and load that into the UIWebView

`[self.webView loadHTMLString:@"<script src=\"demo.js\"></script>"
              baseURL:[NSURL fileURLWithPath:[[NSBundle mainBundle] resourcePath]]];`

Here is the code to make JS call

```
NString *str=@"hi JavaScript";
NSString *function = [[NSString alloc] initWithFormat: @"hello(%@)", str];
NSString *result = [webView stringByEvaluatingJavaScriptFromString:function];
```

Now, there is one important safety tip to make this actually work: The UIWebView must actually be loaded a view. It doesn’t have to be visible, but in order for the WebKit engine to execute the JS, it must be on a view.