# how to load NSData to UIWebView without creating a binary file first

Tags: objective-c, ios, uiwebview, nsdata

Some help needed, please:

I have an NSData ready with bytes (it's an RTF formatted text).

I'd like to be able to load the said NSData into a UIWebView without having to create a binary file first, so in other words without having to do this:

```
[UIWebView loadRequest:[NSURLRequest requestWithURL:[NSURL fileURLWithPath:[[NSBundle mainBundle] pathForResource:@"test" ofType:@"rtf"]isDirectory:NO]]]; }
```

I need to call this many times, so I'd like to avoid saving NSData into a binary file every time. Thank you.

Comment: Your NSData is just an HTML string?

Comment: it's RTF formatted data.

Comment: Well, I mean, a format that a WebView can accept directly with no modification...I've never tried an RTF file but you can try the post in my answer.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use `loadData:MIMEType:textEncodingName:baseURL:`

```
[webView loadData:data MIMEType:@"application/rtf" textEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding baseURL:someURL];
```

You generally need to provide some kind of URL as the `baseURL`, but it doesn't deeply matter what you use if there are no relative links. (See [loadHTMLString baseURL:nil not working in iOS5](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7981083/loadhtmlstring-baseurlnil-not-working-in-ios5) for more discussion on that.)

Comment: Oh! Excellent!  I didn't know about this method.  You win ^^;

Answer (score 2):

I'm going to assume that your NSData just contains HTML string data.  In that case you can do the following:

```
//Use whatever encoding, I assume UTF8
NSString *html = [[NSString alloc] initWithData:yourData encoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];
[yourWebView loadHTMLString:html baseURL:pathToYourHtml];
[html release]; //Not needed in ARC
```