# How to get Redirected URL

Tags: iphone, html, objective-c, ios, xcode

I have a URL.when i try to open it in browser, it will redirect to another URL & display the Content. I want that content But i don't get that redirected URL. So, I can't able to display data.

How can i do that programmatically??

**e.g. URL which i have :** http://www.windpowerengineering.com/?p=11020

**& the redirected URL is:** http://www.windpowerengineering.com/design/mechanical/blades/bladeless-turbine-converts-wind-into-fluid-power/

**I want this redirected URL**. How can i get this?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

1) Specify that your class conforms to the UIWebViewDelegate protocol (and make sure your WebView's delegate outlet is connected to your view controller):

```
@interface YourWebsiteViewController : UIViewController <UIWebViewDelegate>
```

2) Add the following delegate method:

```
-(void)webViewDidStartLoad:(UIWebView *)webView
{
    NSURL *url = [webView.request mainDocumentURL];
    NSLog(@"The Redirected URL is: %@", url);
}
```

Depending on what you're trying to do with this information, you might want to substitute #2 for this method (which will allow you the opportunity to prevent a page from loading):

```
- (BOOL)webView:(UIWebView *)webView shouldStartLoadWithRequest:(NSURLRequest *)request navigationType:(UIWebViewNavigationType)navigationType
{
    NSURL *url = [request mainDocumentURL];
    NSLog(@"The Redirected URL is: %@", url);
    // Return YES if you want to load the page, and NO if you don't.
    return NO;
}
```

Comment: yes,its work but i want to get redirected url **before web-view load** & show.

Comment: i get null as a url for first two/ three times & is there another way to get redirected URL without using webview delegate method?  Because i want to display only specific portion of the html.

Comment: the delegate method of web-view did finish load call more than one time.

Comment: A couple of possible strategies you could implement: 1) Set a property with the initial URL and check to make sure it's not null and different in the delegate before doing anything with the new URL.  If it's different, re-set and check the same property so you don't do anything for the subsequent calls to the delegate method.

Comment: 2) Use the NSURLRequest to get the HTML content you want (instead of passing it to the UIWebView with `loadRequest:`).  You could implement the delegate `NSURLConnectionDataDelegate` and capture redirection URLs with the delegate method `connection:willSendRequest:redirectResponse:`.  Once you have your URL string, send it to the UIWebView with `loadHTMLString:baseURL:` Check out the selected answer here for the last step: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7981083/loadhtmlstring-baseurlnil-not-working-in-ios5

Answer (score 0):

use javascript

```
document.referrer
```

Answer (score 0):

That URL is part of the http header. This is what happening:

request 1: http://www.windpowerengineering.com/?p=11020

response 1: page has moved go to http://www.windpowerengineering.com/design/mechanical/blades/bladeless-turbine-converts-wind-into-fluid-power/

and then your browser will go:

request 2: http://www.windpowerengineering.com/design/mechanical/blades/bladeless-turbine-converts-wind-into-fluid-power/

response 3: here is the html

If you look at the http headers from response 1 you will be able to extract the url from the `Location` header. In Objective C this is one way to do it:

```
NSURLResponse* response = // the response, from somewhere
NSDictionary* headers = [(NSHTTPURLResponse *)response allHeaderFields];
NSString* redirection_url = [headers objectForKey:@"Location"];
```

In the above code you can access all of the response http headers from the `headers` dictionary.

Comment: how can i get location header programmatically

Comment: can you help me with some code because i didn't get your point like how to get response from request1

Answer (score 0):

Did you try this delegate method?

```
-(BOOL)webView:(UIWebView *)webView shouldStartLoadWithRequest:(NSURLRequest *)request navigationType:(UIWebViewNavigationType)navigationType{
```

It will be called whenever the webview loads a webpage.

You can get the URL from one of this method's parameters, `request`

```
    NSURL *regURL=[request URL];
NSString *urlString=[regURL absoluteString];
```

Comment: i get urlString as a about:blank