# iOS to get redirected URL

Tags: ios, url, redirect

In my iOS project, I need to invoke a url https://myemail.mycompany.com/?qs=23263726373273ADSD892329389DFDJFHD232323 and its redirects to another URL http://redr.mycompany.com/first/location/id/next/a/. I need to get the redirected URL in my iOS code and I will write my logic to parse it. How can I do that, can some one help me on this.

Comment: have you tried to implement openurl method ?

Comment: no, I am new to iOS, can you give an example?

Comment: could you describe the use case and scenario ? will you be opening the url in safari or something ?

Comment: I am tapping on a mail have hyper links (like https://myemail.mycompany.com/?qs=23263726373273ADSD892329389DFDJFHD232323). When I tap the mail in my macbook, it will redirect to the web page like http://redr.mycompany.com/first/location/id/next/a/. But if I am taping on the mail from iPhone, as we enabled the universal linking, the app will be opened, and its working good. But I need to get the redirect url in the app and do my custom logic there. Hope I explained the problem, please tell me if anything un clear.

Comment: Try [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/13506281/1971013) and if it works, please up that answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> **From what I inferred is that you want to capture the link that
>   redirects to the app when clicked.**
>
> If that's right, then you need to implement a method in your app
>   delegate class

```
   @available(iOS 9.0, *)
    func application(_ app: UIApplication, open url: URL, options: [UIApplicationOpenURLOptionsKey : Any]) -> Bool {

          return true
    }

    @available(iOS 8.0, *)
    func application(_ application: UIApplication, open url: URL, sourceApplication: String?, annotation: Any) -> Bool {

      if url.scheme == "SOMETHING YOU WANT TO MATCH" {

           return false

      }

      if url.host == "SOMETHING YOU WANT TO MATCH" {

          return false

      }

          return true
    }
```

**Refer this [link](http://blogs.innovationm.com/deferred-deep-linking-in-ios-with-universal-link/) for more detail, it describe all the scenarios and implementations as well.**

Comment: let me know if it helped or it was something else you wanted to ask.

Comment: Thank you Umar for your help.

I am getting the URL (https://myemail.mycompany.com/?qs=23263726373273ADSD892329389DFDJFHD232323)  where user clicked in the email in the method - application:(UIApplication *)application continueUserActivity...

But what I need is, the redirect URL of that - like http://redr.mycompany.com/first/location/id/next/a/

Comment: Can you try putting the breakpoint in all these methods and then check the arguments of the function? I am positive that it's available in these arguments of open URL function